# Is diving across the finish line in Fall Guys faster than just running?

Tags: fall-guys-ultimate-knockout

I feel like I've dived past people to barely qualify, but I haven't analyzed it in-depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is faster. If you were to do it to get ahead of someone, it would slow you down quite a bit when landing. It gains you a little speed and distance when doing it. For example, like in Minecraft when you run and jump at the same time, you move faster instead of just running.